# Unable to solve this error in android (ide : eclipse) - "Syntax error on token "Login", delete this token"

Tags: android, file, generated

```
 public static final class menu {
        public static final int admin_page=0x7f0c0000;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int Admin Login=0x7f0a0020;//HERE IS THE ERROR
        /**  Content description for the action bar "home" affordance. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] 
         */
        public static final int abc_action_bar_home_description=0x7f0a0001;
        /**  Formatting string for describing the action bar's title/home/up affordance.
         This is a single tappable "button" that includes the app icon, the Up indicator
         (usually a "<" chevron) and the window title text.
         %1$s is the title. %2$s is the description of what tapping/clicking the whole
         thing is going to do. 
         */
        public static final int abc_action_bar_home_description_format=0x7f0a0005;
        /**  Just like action_bar_home_description_format, but this one will be used
         if the window is also providing subtitle text.
         %1$s is the title. %2$s is the subtitle. %3$s is the description of what
         tapping/clicking the whole thing is going to do. 
         */
```

"this error occurred in (R.java) file.I tried to delete this but failed as it gets generated again."

Comment: Try to rename this Admin Login to Admin_Login

Comment: i tried to write it as Admin_Login, but failed to do so. and it again generates the same error.

Comment: Refactor that variable in your xml or java file. It will be affected in R.java

Comment: You can not edit the R file. It is auto generated. So don't touch it.

Comment: Could you share the code where your are using Admin Login?

Comment: With a `Admin Login` write as `Admin_Login` it does work on my computer. these two classes are inner-classes?

Comment: another problem

when i click on Login of (Admin Login) using CTRL and click it redirects me to Login.java of another Projects package

Comment: Select that variable right click->Refactor->Rename. Try this.

Comment: Is it possible that R.java, which is auto-generated can be used by multiple packages of different android projects ?

I just asked this 'coz m facing the same problem?

Comment: ^_^ Ajantha, i tried to rename it as well, but after few seconds it gets back to same error format mentioned above.

Comment: Try clean and rebuild your project. And R file is unique for each and every projects. It is not a common file for all projects.

Answer (score 0):

This is because it has two name :

- `public` stands for visibility
- `static` is used to make the field the same for all objects
- `final` is used for making the field not modiafable
- `int` is the type
- `Admin` I believe this is the name
- `Login` I believe this is the name
  **two name????**

You must chose one name for the field, not two, or wrote it as java style (Camel case) :
 `public static final int adminLogin = 0x7f0a0020;`.

Comment: i tried to write it as Admin_Login, but failed to do so. and it again generates the same error.

Comment: this is not possible, unless you have an error on the previous line, can you provide more code please?